# "is_int" is not working properly?

Tags: php

I am trying to check, Input is an integer, float or string. This program gives an error on negative inputs, I don't understand why this happen. When i check inputs with "ctype_digit()", is_int section escaped.

```
<?php
$var=fgets(STDIN);
if(is_numeric($var))
{
    //print "$var";
   if(ctype_digit($var) || is_int($var)){
       print "$var";
       print "This type of input is Integer";
   }
   else{
       //print "$var";
       print "This type of input is Float";
   }
}
else{
    print "This type of input is String";
}
?>
```

Comment: I just tested it and it worked with a negative number.  What PHP version are you using?

Comment: What does `var_dump($var);` output?

Comment: Your comment `When i check inputs with "ctype_digit()", is_int section escaped.` is somewhat confusing though.  You do understand what `||` does, right?

Comment: I am using PHP 5.6.4 and I want to say that when I use only if(ctype_digit($var)) it gives an error for negative inputs. and when I use if(is_int($var)), it escaped. Actually, I don't understand what logic should I use for testing this  condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From PHP MANUAL :

[ctype_digit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

> **Note:**
>   This function expects a string to be useful, so for example passing in an integer may not return the expected result. However, also note that HTML forms will result in numeric strings and not integers. See also the types section of the manual.

[is_int](http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-int.php)

> **Note:**
>   To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use is_numeric().

Use a filter like this **filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)** for an integer evaluation.

```
<?php

$var = -10.12;

if(is_numeric($var))
{
    //print "$var";
   if(filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
    var_dump(filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
       print "$var";
       print "This type of input is Integer";
   }
   else{
       //print "$var";
       print "This type of input is Float";
   }
}
else{
    print "This type of input is String";
}
?>
```

Comment: Huge thanks for the help this code is working very well but what should i do if i don't want to print msg from "var_dump()" .

Comment: Just add a // for comment the line that show the var_dump().     
    `//var_dump(filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));` I added the line because i want you see the boolean from the filter.

Answer (score 0):

ctype fails with negative numbers because minus ("-") is not considered to be part of the POSIX digit character class ([0-9.]).  My PHP (5.3) fails with negative strings '-1' as well.

Despite what others have said, filter_vars() is not the appropriate solution.  It may be workable, but the OP is testing primitive values, not trying to sanitize user input.  He is also asking why ctype() doesn't work, and for a variable test that does. filter_vars() also does not work in other common php versions (< 5.2).  Furthermore, his test can be performed without added function calls.

instead of:
if(ctype_digit($var) || is_int($var))

cast it.

```
foreach (array (-1, 0, 1,1.1,'1.1','1','abc','0','-1') as $test)
{
    if (is_numeric($test))
    {
        if ((int) $test == $test) // <-- HERE
        { echo "int: $test\n"; }
        else 
        { echo "float: $test\n"; }
    }
    else 
    { echo "string: $test\n"; }
}

/*
returns:
 int: -1
 int: 0
 int: 1
 float: 1.1
 float: 1.1
 int: 1
 string: abc
 int: 0
 int: -1
*/
```

Note: The (int) will turn any non-integer string into "1", and == against the string will also cast the string to a 1, so for "abc", the   (int) 'abc' == 'abc' will produce 1 == 1 .  That means either the numeric string test will have to happen first or some other pure string test has to happen first.

Note2: It will fail with strings with spaces.  e.g  " 1 ".  Perhaps add `$var=is_string($var) ? trim($var) : $var;`